# Map two models with a matching property to a new model

Tags: c#, mapping, ienumerable

I'll try to explain this the best that I can so it makes sense.

I have two Models - `BuyerProfile` and `Producerprofile`

**BuyerProfile**

```
public class BuyerProfile : IAuditTrack
{
    [KeyProperty(Identity = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int BuyerTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [NonStored]
    public string BuyerTypeDisplay { get; set; }
}
```

**ProducerProfile**

```
public class ProducerProfile : IAuditTrack
{
    [KeyProperty(Identity = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have a simple method on my controller that retrieves all of the profiles in the database and `concatenates` them together.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetAllProfiles()
{
    var buyerProfiles = _profileService.GetAllBuyerProfiles();
    var producerProfiles = _profileService.GetAllProducerProfiles();

    var profiles = buyerProfiles.Concat(producerProfiles);

    return Json(profiles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now what I would like to do is be able to find every `BuyerProfile` and `ProducerProfile` that share the same `UserId` and merge them together into a new model that would look like this:

```
public class BuyerProducerprofile
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string BuyerName { get; set; }
    public string ProducerName { get; set; }
}
```

The current system that I'm building only allows users to complete 1 `BuyerProfile` and 1 `ProducerProfile`.

So for example, in the result set I might have a `BuyerProfile` that contains the following information:

- Id -> 1543
- UserId -> abc123
- Name -> Bob's Buying Company

and a `ProducerProfile` that contains the following information:

- Id -> 1678
- UserId -> abc123
- Name -> Bob's Produce Company

I would like to be able to combine the two into my new model so that it looks something like this:

- UserId -> abc123
- BuyerName -> Bob's Buying Company
- ProducerName -> Bob's Produce Company

I'm not sure if this is at all possible without using some kind of `Nuget` package but it would be awesome if I didn't have to use one that I don't already have.

I also am currently using `AutoMapper` to do some of my mapping but I couldn't find any documentation that shows being able to use it to do this.

Comment: are you using any sort of framework to access your database?  such as Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want to do is called a join.  you can do it like this

```
var buyerProfiles = _profileService.GetAllBuyerProfiles();
var producerProfiles = _profileService.GetAllProducerProfiles();

var combinedProfiles = 
    from bp in buyerProfiles
    join pp in producerProfiles on bp.UserId equals pp.UserId
    select new BuyerProducerprofile()
    {
        UserId = pp.UserId, 
        BuyerName = bp.Name,
        ProducerName = pp.Name 
    }
```

note: if the same user can have more than one of a type of profile, this will return a result for every combination of buyer profile and producer profile that can be made for that user.

other note:  this is what is called an "inner join", and it will only give you results for users that have both profiles.  You can do other kinds of joins too, but syntax for those joins doesn't feel very natural, and I don't have them committed to memory.  I'm sure a google search can find the syntax for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Yes, I do actually want a join that will still give me all of the profiles but just `null` the values which don't match. I didn't realize you could do joins like this though so thanks a bunch for guiding me there!